# OpenAI gym 0.10.9 'module' object has no attribute 'benchmark_spec'

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

benchmark = gym.benchmark_spec('Atari40M')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'benchmark_spec'

I just got this error for gym-0.10.9. Any idea? Thx

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/1080) on GitHub, the function 'benchmark_spec' is no longer supported.